# What is the difference between code signing services?

Tags: windows, certificate, ssl-certificate, signing

We are developing a new software for windows and would like to sign our code to gain users trust.

There are several companies that offer this service and the prices are also pretty different.

I'm not looking for a recommendation for a specific service - I just want to know what could be different and what to look for in those suppliers?

Thanks

Comment: The first part of the question ("what's the difference between the services") seems pretty good.  The second part ("which one is best for us") seems likely to be closed as "too localized" or "not a real question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important: Please note the comment below! Mozilla and Google are removing the CA from the trusted list.**

They are basically all the same. You pay for the service to get a *Certificate* for *AuthentiCode* based signing of Libraries, Applications or Files. You pay each CA for the same thing: The validation if you exist and who you are. They will then create a Certificate for you which guarantees that you are a real person.

If the users sees that your Certificate comes from VeriSign (now Symantec) instead of Digicert that doesn't matter for the user. If a UAC-Control Window with a green trusted style pop's up, 99% of the Users think that this is a secure app, because the screen fade to green instead of yellow or red.

**The business of CAs is pretty well. They are working with trust. An unlimited good, for a small cost but with huge profit.**

The difference between the CAs are mainly the warrenty they offer. VeriSign i.e. offers a 125K$ extended warrenty if someone is basically using your certificate to sign an application. I am not familiar with the strict guidelines in case they will pay this money.

To be honest: They will only pay, if someone uses the certificate they created for you to create a signed malware application i.e. -  You are bound to guidelines who tell you how to keep the certificate secure and private. If you loose your certificate or it is your fault, I can't imagine that they will pay your financial harm.

Compared with StartSSL, VeriSign is more than 10 times more expensive. I can't get the point why the warrenty is worth this difference.

If you need an advice: Stick with [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/). They offer the cheapest service and give you the ability to create

- one AuthentiCode Certificate
- unlimited SSL-Wildcard Certificates
- good Service

for a one time fee of 60$.

P.S. Don't forget to timestamp your signed executable!

Comment: The 60$ certificate from StartSSL is not really a "one-time fee". For 60$, you get a certificate that's valid for 2 years. Furthermore, timestamping is explicitly disabled.

Comment: FYI Google and Firefox are removing the StartSSL root certificates from their trust chain due to StartSLL being bought out by another less reputable company.

Comment: Thank you fret, I've edited my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Comodo has worked for me. It was by far the cheapest when i used them about a year ago. Others had a much higher price for a cert for code signing. 
Unlike SSL certs they do a bit of due diligence background checking on customers. That must be where the extra cost comes in. They make sure the URL and domain registrar addresses and names are real and match with payment name and addresses etc. So make sure you use consistent names and addresses with payment, domain and phones and you should be all set. We had some minor issues getting that all straight at my company.